# Trying to use login form authentication in Symfony2 but getting numerous errors

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

This is my security.yml file:

```
    # you can read more about security in the related section of the documentation
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html
security:
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#encoding-the-user-s-password
    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#hierarchical-roles
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }
                    admin: { password: adminpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_ADMIN' ] }

    # the main part of the security, where you can set up firewalls
    # for specific sections of your app
    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        # the login page has to be accessible for everybody
        demo_login:
            pattern:  ^/demo/secured/login$
            security: false

        # secures part of the application
        demo_secured_area:
            pattern:    ^/demo/secured/
            # it's important to notice that in this case _demo_security_check and _demo_login
            # are route names and that they are specified in the AcmeDemoBundle
            form_login:
                check_path: _demo_security_check
                login_path: _demo_login
            logout:
                path:   _demo_logout
                target: _demo
            #anonymous: ~
            #http_basic:
            #    realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    # with these settings you can restrict or allow access for different parts
    # of your application based on roles, ip, host or methods
    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#security-book-access-control-matching-options
    access_control:
        #- { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: https }

security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/game/, roles: ROLE_USER }
        # Include the following line to also secure the /admin path itself
        # - { path: ^/admin$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/game
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /game/login
                check_path: /game/login_check
```

This is my routing file:

```
login:
    path:     /login
    defaults: { _controller: LoginSecurityBundle:Security:login }

login_login_signup:
    path:     /signup
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup }

login_login_logout:
    path:     /logout
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:logout }

login_login_managerPage:
    path:   /managerPage
    defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager }

login_check:
    path: /login_check
```

this is my securitycontroller:

```
<?php
namespace Login\SecurityBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $session = $request->getSession();

        // get the login error if there is one
        if ($request->attributes->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
                SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)) {
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        } else {
            $error = '';
        }

        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

        return $this->render(
            'LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
            array(
                // last username entered by the user
                'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                'error'         => $error,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

This is my defaultcontroller:

```
<?php

namespace Login\LoginBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Login\LoginBundle\Entity\User;
use Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Stadium;
use Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Team;
use Login\LoginBundle\Entity\Player;
use Login\LoginBundle\Models\Login;

class DefaultController extends Controller {

    public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:User');

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $session->clear();
            $username = $request->get('username');
            $password = sha1($request->get('password'));
            $remember = $request->get('remember');

            $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
            if ($user) {
                if ($remember == 'remember-me') {
                    $login = new Login();
                    $login->setUsername($username);
                    $login->setPassword($password);
                    $session->set('login', $login);
                }
                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
            } else {
                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig', array('name' => 'Login error'));
            }
        } else {
            if ($session->has('login')) {
                $login = $session->get('login');
                $username = $login->getUsername();
                $password = $login->getPassword();
                $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
                if ($user) {
                    return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
                }
            }
            return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
        }
    }

    /*public function indexAction(Request $request) {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();

        //get the login error if there is one
        if($request->attributes->has(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
            $error = $request->attributes->get(
            SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR
            );
        } elseif(null !== $session && $session->has(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR)){
            $error = $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
            $session->remove(SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR);
        }else{
            $error='';
        }

        //last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME);

        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig',
                array(
                    //last username entered by the user
                    'last_username' => $lastUsername,
                    'error'         => $error,
                )
            );
    }*/

    public function signupAction(Request $request) {
        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {

            $firstNames = array(1 => "Kevin", 2 => "Tommy", 3 => "Bert", 4 => "Daan", 5 => "Marouane", 6 => "Gert", 7 => "Steven", 8 => "Mohammed", 9 => "Jaimy", 10 => "Guy", 11 => "Bavo", 12 => "Cameron", 13 => "Ben", 14 => "Carl");
            $lastNames = array("Aerts", "Peeters", "Maes", "Sprengers", "Janssens", "Eelen", "Norm");

            $username = $request->get('username');
            $email = $request->get('email');
            $password = $request->get('password');
            $teamname = $request->get('teamname');
            $stadiumname = $request->get('stadiumname');

            $user = new User();
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setPassword(sha1($password));
            $user->setUsername($username);
            $user->setMoney(1000000);

            $team = new Team();
            $team->setName($teamname);
            $user->setTeamTeamid($team);

            $stadium = new Stadium();
            $stadium->setName($stadiumname);
            $stadium->setTeamTeamid($team);
            $stadium->setAdvertisingboards(4);
            $stadium->setBars(5);
            $stadium->setCupprice(10);
            $stadium->setEastsection(1000);
            $stadium->setFriendlycupprice(10);
            $stadium->setFriendlyprice(10);
            $stadium->setLeagueprice(10);
            $stadium->setNortheastlight(1);
            $stadium->setNorthsection(1000);
            $stadium->setNorthwestlight(1);
            $stadium->setParking(2000);
            $stadium->setPitchstatus(100);
            $stadium->setPitchtype(1);
            $stadium->setScoreboard1(1);
            $stadium->setScoreboard2(1);
            $stadium->setSoutheastlight(1);
            $stadium->setSouthsection(1000);
            $stadium->setSouthwestlight(1);

            $stadium->setToilets(3000);
            $stadium->setWestsection(1000);
            $stadium->setYouthcentre(1);



            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $em->persist($team);
            $em->flush();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            $em->persist($stadium);
            $em->flush();


            for ($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++) {
                $player = new Player();
                $firstName = rand(0, count($firstNames));
                $lastName = rand(0, count($lastNames));
                $player->setName($firstName . " " . $lastName); //nog veranderen
                $player->setTeamTeamid($team);
                $player->setType("GK");
                $player->setAggression(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBallcontrol(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBirthday(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                $player->setCourage(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setExperience(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setFitness(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setFlexibility(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setGoalkicks(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setMorale(100);
                $player->setPlayalong(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setReflex(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setSpeed(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setJumping(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setStamina(rand(60, 100));
                $rating = ($player->getBallcontrol() + $player->getCourage() + $player->getExperience() + $player->getFitness() + $player->getFlexibility() + $player->getGoalkicks() + $player->getPlayalong() + $player->getReflex() + $player->getSpeed() + $player->getJumping() + $player->getStamina()) / 12;
                $player->setRating($rating);
                $em->persist($player);
                $em->flush();
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++) {
                $player = new Player();
                $firstName = rand(0, count($firstNames));
                $lastName = rand(0, count($lastNames));
                $player->setName($firstName . " " . $lastName); //nog veranderen
                $player->setTeamTeamid($team);
                $typeRandom = rand(1, 3);
                switch ($typeRandom) {
                    case 1:
                        $player->setType("LB");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $player->setType("CB");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $player->setType("RB");
                }

                $player->setAggression(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBallcontrol(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBirthday(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                $player->setPassing(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setExperience(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setFitness(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setShooting(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setPlayitout(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setMorale(100);
                $player->setStrength(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setHeading(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setSpeed(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setTackling(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setStamina(rand(60, 100));
                $rating = ($player->getBallcontrol() + $player->getPassing() + $player->getExperience() + $player->getFitness() + $player->getShooting() + $player->getPlayitout() + $player->getStrength() + $player->getHeading() + $player->getSpeed() + $player->getTackling() + $player->getStamina()) / 12;
                $player->setRating($rating);
                $em->persist($player);
                $em->flush();
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $player = new Player();
                $firstName = rand(0, count($firstNames));
                $lastName = rand(0, count($lastNames));
                $player->setName($firstName . " " . $lastName); //nog veranderen
                $player->setTeamTeamid($team);
                $typeRandom = rand(1, 3);
                switch ($typeRandom) {
                    case 1:
                        $player->setType("LM");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $player->setType("CM");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $player->setType("RM");
                }

                $player->setAggression(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBallcontrol(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBirthday(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                $player->setPassing(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setExperience(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setFitness(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setShooting(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setPlaymaking(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setMorale(100);
                $player->setStrength(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setHeading(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setSpeed(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setTackling(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setStamina(rand(60, 100));
                $rating = ($player->getBallcontrol() + $player->getPassing() + $player->getExperience() + $player->getFitness() + $player->getShooting() + $player->getPlaymaking() + $player->getStrength() + $player->getHeading() + $player->getSpeed() + $player->getTackling() + $player->getStamina()) / 12;
                $player->setRating($rating);
                $em->persist($player);
                $em->flush();
            }
            for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
                $player = new Player();
                $firstName = rand(0, count($firstNames));
                $lastName = rand(0, count($lastNames));
                $player->setName($firstName . " " . $lastName); //nog veranderen
                $player->setTeamTeamid($team);
                $typeRandom = rand(1, 3);
                switch ($typeRandom) {
                    case 1:
                        $player->setType("LF");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        $player->setType("CF");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        $player->setType("RF");
                }

                $player->setAggression(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBallcontrol(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setBirthday(date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
                $player->setPassing(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setExperience(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setFitness(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setShooting(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setInsight(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setMorale(100);
                $player->setStrength(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setHeading(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setSpeed(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setTackling(rand(60, 100));
                $player->setStamina(rand(60, 100));
                $rating = ($player->getBallcontrol() + $player->getPassing() + $player->getExperience() + $player->getFitness() + $player->getShooting() + $player->getInsight() + $player->getStrength() + $player->getHeading() + $player->getSpeed() + $player->getTackling() + $player->getStamina()) / 12;
                $player->setRating($rating);
                $em->persist($player);
                $em->flush();
            }

            return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:succesfullSignup.html.twig');
        }
        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:signup.html.twig');
    }

    public function logoutAction(Request $request) {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->clear();
        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
    }

    public function managerAction(Request $request) {
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $repository = $em->getRepository('LoginLoginBundle:User');
        if ($session->has('login')) {
            $login = $session->get('login');
            $username = $login->getUsername();
            $password = $login->getPassword();
            $user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password));
            if ($user) {
                return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
            }
        }
        //return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:manager.html.twig', array('user' => $user));
        return $this->render('LoginLoginBundle:Default:login.html.twig');
    }

}
```

I am having trouble to get my login system to work. This is my website:

1. Go to the website, you get on the home page with a login form on it
2. Submit the form and you get in your account page (so this page needs to be secured)

With this code I get the following error:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/login_check". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
```

I reread the documentation, did everything again from scratch but I can't get it to work .... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `login_check: { path: /login_check }` is missing it's `defaults` option.

Comment: According to the documentation this isnt necessary, what should that option be?

Comment: Something like > `login_check: { path:   /login_check, defaults: { _controller: LoginLoginBundle:Default:check } }` Basically, your route needs a controller to be handled and of course an action too.

Comment: Now I get this error:
Controller "Login\LoginBundle\Controller\DefaultController::loginAction" for URI "/login_check" is not callable.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `defaults: { _controller: LoginSecurityBundle:Security:login }` in your case? Or, if you want it to keep it in this particular controller, create a `loginAction`

Comment: yes this works, but when submitting the form it goes back to login page, how can I redirect to the accounts page

Comment: You can read for [redirection](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#redirecting) here.

Comment: Ok the redirection works, however I can't retrieve my user, i'm using this code:
public function redirectAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
        return $this->render(
    'LoginLoginBundle:Default:welcome.html.twig', array('user'=>$user)
);
    }

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with you security.yml file, it is a mess!  I honestly have no idea what you are trying to accomplish.
You should make your security.yml file so it only has a single `security` block, and you also should only need a max of 2 firewalls for your purposes.  You also have 2 firewalls that are named the same, so that won't work.  you are also mixing http basic auth with the form based authentication.

If form based authentication is what you want, here is an example security.yml that should work.

```
security:
    encoders: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            pattern: ^/ # everything will go through this firewall
            form_login:
                login_path:  login # the route name for your login route
                check_path:  login_check # the rout name for your login check route
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
            anonymous: true # only paths that require a non anonymous role will be password protected


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/game/, role: ROLE_USER }
```

Give this a shot, and then let us know if you have any more problems.

Comment: this just gives me this: InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "0, 1" under "security.firewalls.access_control"

Comment: I can login with 'user' and 'userpass' now but not with a user from the database

Comment: that's because your provider is set to get users from memory (or the users you define in this security.yml file)  If you want to load users from the database, read the docs [load users from the database](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#loading-users-from-the-database).  You need to adapt the code for your own use, copying and pasting will only get you so far.